# How to generate dynamic url with state in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, dynamic-url

I want to dynamic the URL with {this.state.whatever} in componentDidMount but failed. Because the state value is undefined(I run the console.log and the error also shows it)

I thought componentDidMount runs after the state reset, so I can use the updated state in the URL but doesn't work, I wonder why

```
state={ breed: "" }
async componentDidMount(){
   try {
       const res = await 
       fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${this.state.breed}/images`);
       const data = await res.json();
       const imageUrl = data.message;
       this.setState({
         puppyImage: imageUrl
       })

   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
 }

 onChangeHandler = event => {
   this.setState({breed: event.target.value})
 };
```

this URL doesn't work because of {this.state.breed} is undefined, which means it hasn't been updated.
the error shows:
`GET https://dog.ceo/api/breed//images 404`

Comment: ```this.state.bread``` is ```empty``` not ```undefined```

Comment: ```componentDidMount``` is run when you component mounted. It is not run when ```state``` or ```props``` change. Please read ```React``` document carefully https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: What you need is ```componentDidUpdate```.

Comment: Hi Bowei, see my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tien, I will check out the link you post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` will only run a **single** time after the component renders, and never again.

You should use `componentDidUpdate()` instead which is triggered anytime the component gets an updated state or props. Within it, you can configure logic to determine whether you should do a new `fetch`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(prevState.breed !== this.state.breed){
     try {
       const res = await 
       fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${this.state.breed}/images`);
       const data = await res.json();
       const imageUrl = data.message;
       this.setState({
         puppyImage: imageUrl
       })

     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
   }
 }
```

Under the assumption that you do something that changes `this.state.breed`. The `componentDidUpdate()` logic defined above would trigger then check if their is a difference between the previous breed state and the updated breed state. If there is, then a new fetch-call is made with that breed and you will get a new puppyImage :).

Comment: Thank you, Christopher, the solution you provided works!!

Comment: And I like your explanation, pretty clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @BoweiYao that's awesome! i'm glad this solution worked for you. Please consider upvoting and marking it as the solution (check button). Let me know if you have any other questions :)